# Sort a Raster attribute field in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, combine, sorting

I need to combine several rasters. One of them has an alphanumeric data in the attribute I need to combine. However, when combined the output raster has a 'LONG' attribute type where should be 'STRING' (I believe it's due the first row in that attribute is a number, not an alphanumeric character, so the combine tool assign a 'LONG' type instead of a 'STRING').

How can I create a sorted new raster, where characters go first and then numbers in the mentioned attribute?

I've tried:

1. sort the raster (Descending), then export data to a new raster. Didn't work.
2. sort the raster (D), then lookup tool. Didn't work.

How can I sort a raster attribute, and save the sorted changes?

Comment: You can use Sort tool from data management Arctoolbox to sort  the attribute based on field permanently. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/sort.htm

Comment: Thanks @ahmadhanb, but I'm using 10.2 (that was so close to solve my problem!)

Comment: I'd create string field in combined raster and transfer text from problematic raster by using join and field calculator. Sorting raster attribute table is non-sense